Why Livewire update form by default life
I have Liveware form in modal. And when I keyup some properties, form send function updated. But I need only when I submit. Why? In documentation there is only when submit( I have tried wire:modal.lazy and form wire:submit.prevent but have the same
public $title;
public $quantity;
public $note;
protected $rules = [
    'title' => 'required|min:5',
    'quantity' => 'integer',
    'note' => ''
];

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.popups.add-product-form');
}

public function updated($propertyName)
{
    $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
}

public function save(Service $service)
{
    $data = $this->validate();
    $product = $service->store($data);
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('product-saved', ['action' => 'created']);
    $this->resetForm();
    $this->emitTo('main', 'triggerRefresh');
}


public function resetForm()
{
    $this->title = null;
}


<form wire:submit="save">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">
          <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" wire:model="title" placeholder="Продукт">
            {{-- @error('title') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror --}}
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" wire:model="quantity" placeholder="1" value="1">
          </div>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-floating">
          <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Leave a comment here" id="note" name="note" wire:model="note"></textarea>
          <label for="note">Add Comment</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Создать</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

